# Is WordPress's timezone supposed to be set to UTC within themes and plugins?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a custom theme and plugin for WordPress and noticed that calls to `date_default_timezone_get()` return "UTC" even though:

1. PHP is configured to the local timezone.
2. Wordpress is set to the local timezone in Settings:General:Timezone.

Is this correct behaviour for WordPress, or do I have something misconfigured, a bad plugin, etc.?

Do I need to switch to my local timezone before any calls to PHP's date and time functions (and then restore it later)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, WordPress does work in UTC internally so the values you get from PHP’s `date()`, `time()`, etc. functions will be in UTC as well. You could wrap these in calls to `date_default_timezone_set()` but that gets messy.

It's generally easier to use WordPress’s built-in [current_time()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/) function.

It can return a formatted date (like you would get using PHP’s `date()` function) or a timestamp (like you would get by calling PHP’s `time()` function). A returned time value can be used to seed PHP's other date/time functions. By default `current_time()` returns values for the local timezone.

NOTE: Do not switch to your local timezone using `date_default_timezone_set()` before calling `current_time()` or you will get bad values from it.